# How to Set column size of Element-UI table without words breaking to the next line?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

How to Set column size of Element-UI table without words breaking to the next line?

please check the `address` column in  https://codepen.io/rameezcubet/pen/QWLoMbr

I have `min-width="100"`, so where content is larger than 100px it should expand, but it goes to the next line.

Documentation: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Comment: Did you found a workaround? I'm trying to have a column that adjust to the content and not brek words.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this not possible with element-ui. Not even with css as element-ui generates 2 separate tables 1 for header and 1 for the body.

So if you not want to enlarge the min-width you could maybe use the `show-overflow-tooltip` property or you'll have to create your own table with plain html.